# Find duplicates of a file by name in a directory recursively - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, shell, find, duplicates

I have a folder which contains sub folders and some more files in them.

The files are named in the following way

```
abc.DEF.xxxxxx.dat
```

I'm trying to find the duplicate files only matching 'xxxxxx' in the above pattern ignoring the rest. The extension .dat doesn't change. But the length of abc and DEF might change. The order of separation by periods also doesn't change.

I'm guessing I need to use [Find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/find.1.html) in the following way

```
find -regextype posix-extended -regex '\w+\.\w+\.\w+\.dat'
```

I need help coming up with the regular expression. Thanks.

Example:
For a file named 'epg.ktt.crwqdd.dat', I need to find duplicate files containing 'crwqdd'.

Comment: Have you tried `find -type f -iname 'abc.DEF.*.dat'`?

Comment: @hek2mgl Sorry for lacking clarity in that regard. 'abc' and 'DEF' values/lengths change. So there can be a file like 'epg.ktt.crwqdd.dat'. I need to find duplicates of 'crwqdd' in this example. Thank you.

Comment: And `find -type f -iname '*.*.crwqdd.dat'`?

Comment: @hek2mgl That works only for finding duplicates of crwqdd. But there might be file names containing a different string instead of crwqdd for which there can be matches. So I have no choice but to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
find /path -type f -name '*.dat' | awk -F. 'a[$4]++'
```

**Explanation:**

Let `find` give the following output:

```
./abd.DdF.TTDFDF.dat
./cdd.DxdsdF.xxxxxx.dat
./abc.DEF.xxxxxx.dat
./abd.DdF.xxxxxx.dat
./abd.DEF.xxxxxx.dat
```

Basically, spoken with the words of a computer, you want to count the occurrences of a pattern between `.dat` and the next dot and print those lines where pattern appeared at least the second time.

To achieve this we split the file names by the `.` what gives us 5(!) fields:

```
 echo ./abd.DEF.xxxxxx.dat | awk -F. '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4  " " $5}'
  /abd DEF xxxxxx dat
```

Note the first, empty field. The pattern of interest is `$4`.

To count the occurrences of a pattern in `$4` we use an associative array `a` and increment it's value on each occurrence. Unoptimized, the `awk` command will look like:

```
... | awk -F. '{{if(a[$4]++ > 1){print}}'
```

However, you can write an `awk` program in the form:

```
CONDITION { ACTION }
```

What will give us:

```
... | awk -F. 'a[$4]++ > 1 {print}'
```

`print` is the default action in `awk`. It prints the whole current line. As it is the default action it can be omitted. Also the `>1` check can be omitted because `awk` treats integer values greater than zero as `true`. This gives us the final command:

```
... | awk -F. 'a[$4]++'
```

To generalize the command we can say the pattern of interest isn't the 4th column, it is the next to last column. This can be expressed using *number of fields* in `awk` its `NF`:

```
... | awk -F. 'a[$(NF-1)]++'
```

Output:

```
./abc.DEF.xxxxxx.dat
./abd.DdF.xxxxxx.dat
./abd.DEF.xxxxxx.dat
```

Comment: Thanks! I tested it out and here is the output http://s28.postimg.org/n146n1nil/Capture.png  It doesn't seem to include the last file 'cdd.DxdsdF.xxxxxx.dat' which should be matched. Can you please explain how the above command works? so that I can iron out the issues. Thanks again!

Comment: check my update. you need to count $4 - the fourth column - not the third. That's because the first column will be empty.

Comment: Thank you hek2mgl for taking time to clearly explain it. Much appreciated!!

Comment: No, problem :) Interesting problem, was fun to solve.

Comment: That's an awesome attitude to have!! 
Also, how can I adjust/modify the 'if' statement to get the following results:
Find duplicates of a[$4] but exclude those files which have the same a[$2]? thanks again!

Comment: You can use this one `... | awk -F. 'a[$(NF-1)]++ && !a[$(NF-3)]++'`